# ExtJs 4.2 nested prompt message box

Tags: javascript, extjs, messagebox, extjs4.2

I have a code which looks like this:

```
        Ext.Msg.prompt( Translation.RefusalMessageBoxTitle, "", 
            function(btn, text, cfg ){

                if(btn == 'ok' && Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
                    var newMsg = '<span style="color:red;" class="error">' + Translation.RefusalMessageBoxEmpty + '</span>';
                    Ext.Msg.show(Ext.apply({}, { msg: newMsg }, cfg));
                }else if( btn !== 'ok' ){
                    return;
                }else if( btn == 'ok' ){
                    this.sendRefusalAnswer( methodName, text, "reject", Constant.DocumentStatus.REFUSED, me.selectedDocument.get('id'));
                }

            }, this, true, '' );
```

Now mz problem is that the

```
 var newMsg = '<span style="color:red;" class="error">' + Translation.RefusalMessageBoxEmpty + '</span>';
                        Ext.Msg.show(Ext.apply({}, { msg: newMsg }, cfg));
```

part of the code gets executed, but then the box closes imidietly... how can i prevent that??? any ideas?

EDIT:

This happens only on EXTJS 4.2 build 
Build date: 2013-03-11 22:33:40 (aed16176e68b5e8aa1433452b12805c0ad913836) ONLY!!!!!

the version 
Build date: 2013-05-16 14:36:50 (f9be68accb407158ba2b1be2c226a6ce1f649314)
works just fine °-°

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted it to a message object:

```
        Ext.Msg.show({ 

            title: Translation.RefusalMessageBoxTitle, 
            minWidth: this.minPromptWidth,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
            callback: function(btn, text, cfg ){

                if(btn == 'ok' && Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
                    var newMsg = '<span style="color:red;" class="error">' + Translation.RefusalMessageBoxEmpty + '</span>';
                    Ext.Msg.show(Ext.apply({}, { msg: newMsg }, cfg));
                }else if( btn !== 'ok' ){
                    return;
                }else if( btn == 'ok' ){
                    this.sendRefusalAnswer( methodName, text, "reject", Constant.DocumentStatus.REFUSED, me.selectedDocument.get('id'));
                }

            }, 
            scope:this, 
            multiline: true,  

        });
```

But still cant figure out how to prevent it from closing on me °_°

Comment: I would check the JS console when you run this and ensure that some other error isn't causing the MessageBox to close. When I run your code as is, it produces the behavior you describe because the variables are not defined. When I replace the undefined variables with something that is defined, however, it works precisely as you want it to. See this working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mc

Comment: Zour example dous the same thing my dous.... it leaves a gray overlay on the site which i cant remove. That is the problem i fighting atm.

Comment: I don't see where it's doing that. Moreover, this is not the issue you mentioned in the original question...

Comment: True. But that solution makes the user interface lock up after you click anywhere so it is not usable at all.

Comment: I don't see it doing that either. I think you have a bug elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `Ext.Msg` singleton, but rather regular windows or create multiple instances of [`Ext.window.MessageBox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox) yourself. The singleton is itself a window, and the component is shared by all  calls to `alert`, `confirm`, `prompt`, etc., so it won't be possible to show multiple windows at the same time with it.

Comment: I dont want to show multiple windows just prevent it from closing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it... the damn build version was diferent on mz build machine.

I locally have

Build date: 2013-03-11 22:33:40 (aed16176e68b5e8aa1433452b12805c0ad913836)

And on mz test machine we have

Build date: 2013-05-16 14:36:50 (f9be68accb407158ba2b1be2c226a6ce1f649314)

On my local it dous not work... but on the test machin it works without problems... 3 MONTHS! wtf!